# How to create yourself "tailed-function: like object array but function" as Laravel does in its eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel eloquent has great job for managing queries. We can easily put simple statistics on it. For example, I have table called "Students" then I try to count boys only as follow:

```
$total = Students::where(['sex'=>'boy'])->count();
```

I use service provider for creating my own function that I am able to call them using the format `SomeClass::MyFunction()`. My question is how to create function like-object array so that I can call them as follow:

```
$var = SomeClass::MyFunction()->newFunction();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried reading [the Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) to see how they do it?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes, I have already. I used sublime text to identify where the definition came from. I ended up at a js bundle, which seemed complicated for now. I had an alternative to simply use multiple parameters instead of standing new function. But, using something that I asked above improves my codes to get tidier. Thank you for your response.